# Sugarcrm during Reports generation retrieve data from related fields

Tags: php, relationship, sugarcrm

I am trying to retrieve data from "Opportunities" Reports.

This is my scenario: Opportunity module, field `sales_person` is a realated field from `users` module.

In `Bids` modules I have a `relate` field with opportunities.

During report generation, I am trying to retrieve the `sales_person` name in opportunities. But it is not listing in `Bids` report field_lists.

My dictionary in `Bids`

```
'opportunity_id_c' => array(
            'required' => false,
            'name' => 'opportunity_id_c',
            'vname' => 'LBL_OPPORTUNITY_OPPORTUNITY_ID',
            'type' => 'id',
            'reportable' => true,
            'calculated' => false,
            'len' => 36,
            'size' => '20',
        ),
        'opportunity' => array(
            'required' => false,
            'source' => 'non-db',
            'name' => 'opportunity',
            'vname' => 'LBL_OPPORTUNITY',
            'type' => 'relate',
            'reportable' => true,
            'unified_search' => false,
            'merge_filter' => 'disabled',
            'len' => '255',
            'size' => '20',
            'id_name' => 'opportunity_id_c',
            'ext2' => 'Opportunities',
            'module' => 'Opportunities',
            'rname' => 'name',
            'quicksearch' => 'enabled',
            'studio' => 'visible',
        ),
```

Relationship:

```
$dictionary['Opportunity']['fields']['opportunities_procurements'] = [
    'name' => 'opportunities_procurements',
    'type' => 'link',
    'relationship' => 'opportunities_procurements',
    'module' => 'Procurement',
    'bean_name' => 'Procurement',
    'source' => 'non-db',
    'vname' => '',
];

$dictionary['Opportunity']['relationships']['opportunities_procurements'] = [
    'lhs_module' => 'Opportunities',
    'lhs_table' => 'opportunities',
    'lhs_key' => 'id',
    'rhs_module' => 'Procurement',
    'rhs_table' => 'procurement',
    'rhs_key' => 'opportunity_id_c',
    'relationship_type' => 'one-to-many',
];
```

This is what I tried: I tried to create a similar field `opportunity` in bids module named as `opportunity_sales_user`and in dictionary instead of `'rname' => 'name',` I use `'rname' => 'sales_person',` but I didn't get the data as the `sales_person` is related record.

I couldn't retrieve the vales in `Reports`.

How can I create a full relationship so I can get the `sales_person` value in `Bids` reports generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing same problem so , i choose to write a simple SQL query

```
global $db;
        $query = "Your Sql to get Reports";
        $re = $db->query($query);
        $data = '';
        while ($row = $db->fetchByAssoc($re)) {
            your code
        }
```

Comment: where did u wrote?

Comment: if your doing in dashlet then you have to create custom dashlets